# Does a AzureML webservice overwrite reset the Data Collection Dataset?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

If we have an AzureML web service endpoint that is collecting data (for Data Drift Monitoring), does overwriting the web service endpoint with a new version of the model break links with the Dataset registered for collecting data.

The relative path to this dataset is:
`<Subscription-ID>/<Resource-Group>/<Workspace>/<Webservice-Name>/<model-name>/<version>/inputs/**/inputs*.csv`

If we redeploy a new version using `az ml model deploy ..... --overwrite`, will we need a new reference to a new Dataset for detecting Data Drift?

If we use `az ml service update ..`, will the Dataset reference be kept intact?

Comment: interesting use case. is the endpoint only for capturing incoming data? or it also for scoring?

Comment: for scoring as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Dataset Asset is a simple reference to a location in a Datastore. Assuming the model version and service name does not change, the Dataset reference also will not change. If however, with every Service Update - The model version changes then adding a Dataset with Relative Path:

```
<Subscription-ID>/<Resource-Group>/<Workspace>/<Webservice-Name>/<model-name>/*/inputs/**/inputs*.csv
```

Will solve the problem. Since Data Drift is another service referencing this Dataset asset, it will keep working as expected.